# Consuming SOAP Web Services in Xamarin Forms with just a WSDL File

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, soap, wsdl

I am a web-service n00b and I am trying to figure out how to consume a SOAP web service into a Xamarin Forms project. The catch, however, is that I am only provided with the .wsdl file. Anyone have any ideas or know where to start?

Comment: do you have any other options available?  SOAP is an old technology and awful to work with.  I would avoid it at all costs.  However, if you are stuck with SOAP Xamarin covers this in their docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I do not have another option. The company I am working for already have created the SOAP Web Service and have only given me the .wsdl file to work with. After many hours of looking through documentation/forums, I have tried to add the web reference to the path of the wsdl file in Visual Studio but kept getting the error "There was an error downloading '{0}'".

Comment: Also, I kept running into people saying to use WCF, but I cannot because I am on Mac OS. @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have sadly had to do this in the past. You want to check out using [Svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe),

These are the notes from our old project with some parts redacted but it should be enough to get you going:

- Generate the proxy service wrapper using svcutil e.g.
  `svcutil PATH_TO_HOSTED_WSDL`

Note that different versions of the svcutil tool may give you async methods on the end of the file, or not. These shouldn't matter though. *You probably want `async` here, our dev at the time wasn't so sure though*.

- Then hand edit to the file to remove any reference to `IExtensibleDataObject` e.g

  - Delete section on end of class definitions
    `, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject`
  - Delete field
    `private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;`
  - Delete property

```
public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
{
    get
    {
        return this.extensionDataField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.extensionDataField = value;
    }
}
```

**It certainly seemed at the time we did this last that some constructs were not supported in `Xamarin`. This may not longer be the case but this has worked for us.**

### Update

I have not gone to the lengths of testing this tool but [`dotnet-svcutil`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) appears to be a new `dotnet` tool that should work to generate the required bits to allow for consuming a WCF web service.

Comment: I am on a mac, so I don't believe I can use Silverlight. Any workarounds?

Comment: @DeZLearnsPCs this isn’t using Silverlight but there does appear to be a newer dotnet replacement that runs on macOS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x